# VBA code to copy data from one worksheet & paste below last row of another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a code to import data from one workbook to another.

The **source workbook** will change everytime.

The **target workbook** is **History Statistics**

After importing the data to **source worksheet**: **Sheet 2**, I wish to copy the entire data except headers & paste below the last row of **target sheet**: **Sheet 1**

I am able to do the first part of importing the data into worksheet **Sheet 2**. But I don't know why the code for copy-paste does not give any result even though it runs and gives no error. So, cannot find the error and cannot understand what is going wrong.

Please help me understand the problem! Thanks! :)

This is my code:

```
Public Sub Add_Data()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim TabName As String

TabName = "Sheet 2"

ActiveSheet.Name = TabName

count1 = Workbooks("History Statistics.xlsm").Sheets.Count
Sheets(TabName).Copy After:=Workbooks("History Statistics.xlsm").Sheets(count1)

Workbooks("History Statistics.xlsm").Activate

MsgBox ("Data has been added to the master file")

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim ColList As String, ColArray() As String
Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim boolFound As Boolean
Dim delCols As Range

On Error GoTo Whoa

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'~~> Set your sheet here
Set WS = Sheets("Sheet 2")

'~~> List of columns you want to keep. You can keep adding or deleting from this.
'~~> Just ensure that the column names are separated by a COMMA
'~~> The names below can be in any case. It doesn't matter
ColList = "Object Code, Points, Type, F, Module, Global Resp. Area"

'~~> Create an array for comparision
ColArray = Split(ColList, ",")

'~~> Get the last column
LastCol = WS.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=WS.Range("A1"), Lookat:=xlPart, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
MatchCase:=False).Column

'~~> Get the last row
LastRow = WS.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=WS.Range("A1"), Lookat:=xlPart, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
MatchCase:=False).Row

'~~> Loop through the Cols
For i = 1 To LastCol
    boolFound = False
    '~~> Checking of the current cell value is present in the array
    For j = LBound(ColArray) To UBound(ColArray)
        If UCase(Trim(WS.Cells(1, i).Value)) = UCase(Trim(ColArray(j))) Then
            '~~> Match Found
            boolFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
   '~~> If match not found
    If boolFound = False Then
        If delCols Is Nothing Then
            Set delCols = WS.Columns(i)
        Else
            Set delCols = Union(delCols, WS.Columns(i))
        End If
    End If
Next i

'~~> Delete the unwanted columns
If Not delCols Is Nothing Then delCols.Delete

LetsContinue:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
Whoa:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume LetsContinue

WS.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: At the end, qualify `Cells()` with the sheet too...`WS.Range(WS.Cells(2, 1), WS.Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet 1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)` ?

Comment: @BruceWayne: I just tried it, but does not give me the result.

Comment: Your code is far more complicated then I'd guess from your description, please amend description, or delete non-relevant parts of the code. Have you tried [debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/802/getting-started-with-vba/15512/debugging#t=201705091527354062327) your code? It should show you all the steps it does and you'll be able to see where it behaves differently then you expect.

Comment: @MátéJuhász: Thank you so much giving me the idea of debugging line by line. I figured out the error. The code `WS.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)` should be before the loop starts. Or else the code is running inside the loop and coming to the next line.

Comment: Nice you could use it? Did it resolve your problem? If yes then you're welcome to post it as an answer. If not, then please update your question and explain what's the current issue.

Comment: @MátéJuhász: Will post the correct code as the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the error. The line

```
WS.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

should be before the loop starts. Otherwise the code is running inside the loop and coming to the next line.

```
Public Sub Add_Data()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim TabName As String

TabName = "Sheet 2"

ActiveSheet.Name = TabName

count1 = Workbooks("History Statistics.xlsm").Sheets.Count
Sheets(TabName).Copy After:=Workbooks("History Statistics.xlsm").Sheets(count1)

Workbooks("History Statistics.xlsm").Activate

MsgBox ("Data has been added to the master file")

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim ColList As String, ColArray() As String
Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim boolFound As Boolean
Dim delCols As Range

On Error GoTo Whoa

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'~~> Set your sheet here
Set WS = Sheets("Sheet 2")

'~~> List of columns you want to keep. You can keep adding or deleting from this.
'~~> Just ensure that the column names are separated by a COMMA
'~~> The names below can be in any case. It doesn't matter
ColList = "Object Code, Points, Type, F, Module, Global Resp. Area"

'~~> Create an array for comparision
ColArray = Split(ColList, ",")

'~~> Get the last column
LastCol = WS.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=WS.Range("A1"), Lookat:=xlPart, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
MatchCase:=False).Column

'~~> Get the last row
LastRow = WS.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=WS.Range("A1"), Lookat:=xlPart, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
MatchCase:=False).Row

'~~> Loop through the Cols
For i = 1 To LastCol
boolFound = False
'~~> Checking of the current cell value is present in the array
For j = LBound(ColArray) To UBound(ColArray)
    If UCase(Trim(WS.Cells(1, i).Value)) = UCase(Trim(ColArray(j))) Then
        '~~> Match Found
        boolFound = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
'~~> If match not found
If boolFound = False Then
    If delCols Is Nothing Then
        Set delCols = WS.Columns(i)
    Else
        Set delCols = Union(delCols, WS.Columns(i))
    End If
End If
Next i

'~~> Delete the unwanted columns
If Not delCols Is Nothing Then delCols.Delete

'copy-paste after last row
WS.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

LetsContinue:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
Whoa:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```